# Yahoo address book retrieval

Tags: java, yahoo-api

I am trying to retrieve address book contacts through yahoo. After googling a bit, I came up to number of Yahoo developer pages and the api I was looking for.

However, at the moment I am not in position to give detail about my **Web Application URL** and **BBAuth Success URL** while registering for Yahoo app-id in order to yahoo app working. Since my application decision are still not yet decided. I am trying to make a POC (Proof of concept) for retrieving yahoo/hotmail contacts.

Is there any way that I can get address book details without app-id .. OR .. can I register for app-id without the **Web Application URL** and **BBAuth Success URL** .. OR .. what alternate I could use for a local POC development ? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and register an account with temporary URLs. When you finalize your URLs you can get another key with the real ones, or edit your existing information.

You might also want to check out YQL

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20fields.value%20from%20social.contacts%20where%20guid%3Dme

It doesn't need an API key.

Comment: It asks to place some file on your root direct on the server you mentioned and the yahoo checks for that file, whether that file is there to authenticate and issue the key. we can't use a fake url here to register for an app-id

Comment: you don't own ANY url ANYWHERE? Just use something that you own somewhere. It doesn't have to be your final resting place. Use a free host, googlepages, blogspot, anything.